# PC won't start Windows 7 Setup

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, installation, windows-installation

We have a PC, which doesn't like Windows 7 installation media. Ever since the PC arrived 2 years ago, I get this error when booting from a Windows 7 installation disk or usb drive:

[image]

The only solution to this is to take the HDD out, put it in another PC and then it will install fine.

What's even stranger, is that the PC was recently upgraded. It got a new PSU, CPU, GPU, new memory and a new mobo. The only parts that are the same are the case, the HDD, the DVD drive and the wireless network card.

However, the PC still won't start Windows 7 setup. I've tried different installation dvd's. Also I have a DVD dating back may 2011 that has installed many times correctly.

What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: That error code is impossible to read, how about you type it in for us so we can read it.  Have you tried a new/different optical drive? Or how about try installing windows from a USB stick instead?

Comment: The error code is 0xc00000068. I've already tried installing from USB drive, to no avail

Comment: Maybe some bad configuration of the sata or the memory in your BIOS?

Comment: Well we have had two different motherboards now and for both win7 won't install..  I can have a look at it but I don't think it's a bios setting